# React componentDidMount async/await long polling

Tags: reactjs, async-await, long-polling

Есть сервер, который эмулириует long polling. Нужно слать запросы, пока не придет ответ типа `{tickets: [], stop: true}`.

Есть код:

```
 async getTickets(prevToken) {
  const token = prevToken ? prevToken : await this.getToken();
  const response = await fetch(`https://front-test.beta.aviasales.ru/tickets?searchId=${token}`);

  if (response.ok) {
      let tickets = await response.json();
      if (!tickets.stop) {
          await this.getTickets(token);
      } else {
          return tickets.tickets;
          // console.log(tickets.tickets);
      }
  } else if (response.status == '404') {
      await this.getTickets()
  } else {
      await this.getTickets(token);
  }
 }

async componentDidMount() {
  const tickets = await this.getTickets();

  this.setState(state => ({
    tickets: tickets
  }))
}
```

в стейт возвращает `undefined`. Если же запускаю так, то возвращается правильный массив:

```
async getTickets(prevToken) {
  const token = prevToken ? prevToken : await this.getToken();
  const response = await fetch(`https://front-test.beta.aviasales.ru/tickets?searchId=${token}`);

  if (response.ok) {
      let tickets = await response.json();
      ***return tickets.tickets;***
  } else if (response.status == '404') {
      await this.getTickets();
  } else {
      await this.getTickets(token);
  }
}
```

Каким образом это можно исправить? Примерно понимаю, что проблема возникает из-за растущего стека вызовов, но не хватает знаний, чтобы осилить этот момент.

Comment: попробуйте на **8** строчке  нерабочего кода убрать `await`

Comment: К сожалению, результат тот же

Comment: тогда на той же строчке исправьте на  `return this.getTickets(token)` или `return await  this.getTickets(token)`;

Comment: спасибо, сработало! Можете кратко описать причину возникновения проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тогда продублирую для Вас ответ, что и в комментарии и отпишу в чём *сок* ошибки.

`return this.getTickets(token)` или `return await this.getTickets(token)`.

здесь баг крылся в самом понимании **js** (в стеках вызовов), но он визуально незаметен, так что я случайно догадался.

когда Ваш первый вызов `getTickets` проходит неудачно, Вы заново вызываете `getTickets`. когда Ваш **второй** вызов `getTickets` закончился удачно, Вы возвращаете `tickets` обратно в результат **первого** `getTickets`. и получается вот такое:

```
if (!tickets.stop) {
   await tickets; // результат выполненого второго getTickets, который уже никуда не возвращается (у него нет return)
} else {
   return tickets.tickets;
}
```

затем стек вызовов заканчивается и Ваш **первый** `getTickets` должен закончиться, но он уже ничего не возвращает, так как Вы не указали, что результат                                                `tickets` нужно вернуть. а так как **первый** `getTickets` ничего не возвращает, то по умолчанию его результат будет `return undefined`, как и у всех функциях, которые явно не указывают `return`.

Comment: Спасибо, понял, не хватило мозгов дойти до этого момента.